# how to set image in image view in List Header in android?

Tags: android, list, imageview

I was trying to create a application where i parse JSON data and have thumbnails generated & a List View. Something very similar to the TED app, look at screenshot below :

https://lh6.ggpht.com/52KEhYtmJE-IV7yfMyAF9JZ1K4nTZGsZ-KM1eQG4-yMmlTqv-KaL7b1JE7I2W3wNVw

I was able to succesfully add a Header to my List View  using :

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);

list.addHeaderView(header);

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The header xml file in layout folder  contains a ImageView,i have found the id using

```
iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivback);
```

But my problem is whenever i try to set it to any image , i get a Null Pointer Exception, Loggging it showed that iv is null.

Any idea why iv is null ? since iv is null ,     iv.setImage()  methods dont work.

Thanks in advance

I also confirmed that the link of image i am passing is not null

So how do i set a image to that imageview i have added as a header to my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is null as you should get the image view from the header view not the view of the activity..it should be like:

```
iv=(ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.ivback);
```

Comment: That fixed it ! I forgot to do that :) Thanks